# How can I pass workgroup info to Athena startQueryExecution method in Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-athena

I am seeing the below error when I try to pass WorkGroup info in the format listed below using my boto3 code in AWS Lambda -

> "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in
>   input: \"WorkGroup\", must be one of: QueryString, ClientRequestToken,
>   QueryExecutionContext, ResultConfiguration",

```
query_id = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=query_string,
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': 'sample_db'
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 's3://sample_db/output/'
    },
    WorkGroup='workgroup1'
)['QueryExecutionId']
```

As per boto3 documentation , this is something that can be passed - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution

Comment: What boto3 version are you using? Try updating to the latest one. Note that the one bundled in the Lambda execution environment might not be up-to-date.

Comment: How can I upgrade the version within AWS Lambda?

Comment: You have to bundle boto3 yourself. Add it to the deployment package. Importing it will have precedence.

Comment: Thanks @MilanCermak. However is there a different way of adding workgroup location for Athena using old version of boto3?

Comment: I don't think so. Looks like the `WorkGroup` parameter support got added in boto3 v1.9.97 (see e.g. the docs here for v1.9.96 https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.96/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution where the param is not present).

Comment: Thanks @MilanCermak . I was using python 3.6 instead 3.7. I’ll try with 3.7

Comment: @MilanCermak Even 3.7 seems to have an old version of the library 1.9.42. Is there an upgrade roadmap published by AWS for boto3? I am just trying to figure out if I can use primary workgroup for now and use custom workgroup when AWS upgrade it , if it is in near future.

Comment: Well, yes, the library version is not tied to the language version. I don't know of any such public roadmap. As already mentioned, if you want to use the latest features, you'll have to bundle your own boto3 version. See also https://www.serverlessops.io/blog/aws-lambda-and-python-boto3-bundling

Comment: The version of boto3 that python 3.6 using was 1.7.x whereas it was 1.9.x when I used python 3.7. But it still did get upgraded to the version you specified. Thanks @MilanCermak , I package the boto3 library then.

Comment: @MilanCermak I packaged the latest version of boto as lambda layer and got this working. Thanks for your help. If it is possible for you to post an answer , I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow-up answer from the discussion below the question:

The bundled version of boto3 in the Lambda execution environment is not up to date with the latest boto3 release.

You can make a newer version available either by includin it in the deployment package or adding it as a Lambda Layer.